# Copy text from Chrome’s Reader mode?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Google Chrome’s reading mode side panel is pretty good. It seems (to me) to outperform [readability.js](https://github.com/mozilla/readability), [dom-distiller](https://github.com/chromium/dom-distiller) and [trafilatura](https://trafilatura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on [Google Search](https://www.google.com) and [ACS](https://pubs.acs.org/). So I wanted to feed its output to GPT-4, but it seems currently impossible to copy HTML from the panel. I’m looking for a solution.

### What I've tried

Popular alternative Chrome reader extensions, browser built-in readers and open source solutions. None seemed as capable, or could parse Google Search results.

Old Chrome’s copy-able reading mode (based on [dom-distiller](https://github.com/chromium/dom-distiller) instead of [read-anything](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/b2ec35770a91b45ca3308e83d525cec14f78096e/chrome/renderer/accessibility/read_anything_app_controller.cc)) could still be reproduced on Chrome version 104 with `chrome-distiller://<UUID>_<HASH>/?url=<URL>`, but seemed less satisfactory and stable.

### Solutions I've considered

The reading mode side panel has an accessibility tree (e.g. via Accessibility Inspector on macOS). Theoretically it is possible to programmatically get and parse it, though I have no experience in UI automation.

In Chromium’s source, the `ReadAnythingUntrustedPageHandler::OnCopy` function ([src](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/b2ec35770a91b45ca3308e83d525cec14f78096e/chrome/browser/ui/webui/side_panel/read_anything/read_anything_untrusted_page_handler.cc#L171)) seems to call `main_observer_->web_contents()->Copy()`, the main HTML instead of the distilled one (`web_ui_->GetWebContents()`?). Perhaps the source code can be modified and built, though I have little experience with C++ and big software engineering.

`chrome-untrusted://read-anything-side-panel.top-chrome` and `<read-anything-app />` elements seem to be involved. Perhaps there is a hack to access any of them?

### Summary

There should be no theoretically inherent difficulty in copying the distilled HTML, especially with its source code known. As (it seems) one of the best text extraction solutions, there is a good reason to try using it in research/production.

So how difficult would it be to become able to copy HTML from Chrome’s reading mode side panel, and how might I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following worked on Mac OSX:

1. open reading mode
2. open some text editor (I used VSCode)
3. hold the mouse cursor down and drag it over the desired text in reading mode to mark it
4. release mouse
5. click and drag the marked text into your text editor
6. save or copy/paste the desired text within your text editor

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to get that Reading Mode-style content you're after:

The Network Ninja Way:

If the good stuff is tucked inside a JSON package being sent over the network:
Bust open those Chrome DevTools and head to the "Network" tab.
Hunt down the right request, right-click, and snag that bad boy with "Copy as cURL" (or something similar).
Time to break out your JSON parsing skills!

Puppeteer Power:

For trickier websites, recreating Reading Mode's magic, or grabbing JSON payloads directly, Puppeteer is your friend:
Get it to load the page and kick off Reading Mode (if that's how it works on the site).
Zero in on the content you want (either the cleaned-up HTML or the network request with the JSON).
Extract the text and structure (for HTML) or snatch that JSON payload.

Heads Up:  Websites can be sneaky – be ready for a little detective work figuring out how things are put together.
Got a specific site in mind?
Hit me up, and I can help you crack the code!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

async function extractAndSavePayload() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // Modify as needed
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Replace with your target URL
  await page.goto('https://your-target-website.com');

  // **Important: Update the filter based on your network request**
  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url().endsWith('.json') && interceptedRequest.method() === 'POST') { 
      const payload = interceptedRequest.postData();

      if (payload) {
        fs.writeFileSync('extracted_payload.json', payload);
        console.log('JSON payload saved!');
      }
    }
    interceptedRequest.continue();
  });

  // ... (add steps to trigger your desired action if needed) 

  await browser.close();
}

extractAndSavePayload();
```